android emulator can't post to locally hosted website
I'm trying to make a .net maui application that can post to a website that I am using XAMPP/Apache to host. When using a try catch block the only error message that I get is connection failed and even checking the error logs within xampp shows that there wasn't an attempt to connect.
I've tried adding/changing things in the .conf files as well as changing the ip address in the url however I've made 0 progress
Below is the code behind of my .net maui app
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace AppSiteTest;

public class ApiService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ApiService()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
//post method used in second clicked event
    public async Task<string> SendPostRequestAsync(string url, object data)
    {
        var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }

        return null;
    }
}









public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ApiService _apiService;



    private int rowCount = 0;
    private int columnCount = 0;

    private string _photoPath;
    public string PhotoPath
    {
        get => _photoPath;
        set
        {
            _photoPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PhotoPath));
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        photo_grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100) });
        _apiService = new ApiService();
    }
//ignore this clicked event
    public async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
        {
            FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

            if (photo != null)
            {
                // save the file into local storage
                string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

                using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
                using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);

                if (PhotoPath != null)
                {
                    photo_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(75) });
                    columnCount++;

                    var gridPhoto = new Image
                    {
                        Source = PhotoPath,
                        BackgroundColor = Colors.AliceBlue,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                    };


                    photo_grid.Add(gridPhoto, columnCount, rowCount);

                }

                PhotoPath = localFilePath;
            }
        }

    }
//attempt to post begins
    public async void btn_Post_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        upload_status.Text = "Trying to connect";
        var url = "http://10.0.2.2/GuppyTown_CISP316/php/submit.php";
        var data = new { fname = "John", lname = "Smith", email = "email@gmail.com", phone = "000-000-0000", tip = "From .net Maui" };
        upload_status.Text = "data and url loaded";
        try
        {
            var response = await _apiService.SendPostRequestAsync(url, data);
            upload_status.Text = response ?? "No response from server";
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpEx)
        {
            upload_status.Text = $"Request error: {httpEx.Message} {url}";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            upload_status.Text = $"General error: {e.Message}";
        }
    }


}






have you tried connecting to the url from Chrome in the emulator?

I have successfully connected to the website from the emulator using both 10.0.2.2 and my computers local ip address

Is it true that what you mean is --  when you run the system (maui based) on your smartphone then it fails ?

I meant my problem is when I run my application (maui based) and activate the on click method btn_Post_Clicked it should post the data to my site and add it to a database but it doesn't. I can post from my website to my php but any time I try to post from the maui based app it simply says connection failed

Android also requires https connections unless you explicitly allow it

Is this a problem with C#, with PHP, with HTTP itself, with XAMPP?

@Habibi are you testing this on real device?

@KenLee I've decided everything from my firewall to my antivirus during testing with no results

@Jason Can you explain to me what that means as I'm decently knew to .net maui and android in general

@NicoHaase I'm not quite sure, it seems to me like an http issue as I can't seem to connect nor find where the source of the issue is

@H.A.H. no, I'm using android studio for an emulator but I will try and get a real device to test on

https://www.google.com/search?q=android+cleartexttrafficpermitted+site:stackoverflow.com

@Jason this worked perfectly and my app is now able to post! I added a placeholder answer for now but do you mind adding an answer so I can accept yours?

I don't know how to mark an answer, but Jason came through for me as it ended up being that I had to add (UsesClearTextTraffic = True) to the MainApplication.cs file found at Platforms>Android while I am debugging and testing. Thank you all!
